# Google drive - How to download file to local directory using php

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using Google drive sdk. I am using following code

```
  $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
  $results = $drive_service->files->listFiles();
  $items = $results->getItems();
    foreach($items as $listItem){
        $url[] = $listItem['selfLink'];
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($url); exit;
   There url shows all links.
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to download google drive files. on any specific location

Answer (score 0):

Make use of the client libraries Google has provided for various languages to download files from Google Drive. Assuming that you are using PHP to serve this purpose, this is a nice [quickstart guide for PHP developers](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/php) to embed library to their project and complete the setup. This would involve authentication.

Finally you can use this code to download files from Google Drive using this code:

```
function downloadFile($service, $file) {
  $downloadUrl = $file->getDownloadUrl();
  if ($downloadUrl) {
    $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadUrl, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = $service->getClient()->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
      return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
    } else {
      // An error occurred.
      return null;
    }
  } else {
    // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
    return null;
  }
}
```

For more details visit this [document](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads).

Comment: Thanks for your message But I have tried this code $file->getDownloadUrl(); it always return blank.